# Get around java's try/catch and keep the code clean without returning a null

Tags: java, try-catch

I have this piece of code:

```
private void myFunc(){
   obj = doSomething();
   //If value is found, doX()
   //If value is not found, doY()
}

private obj doSomething(){
  //Do some stuff
  //Hit database to get some value
  obj = db.getValue(); //This func throws an exception if no value is found
}
```

Now, my question is:
1. Should I do: `doSomething() throws ValueNotFoundException` and catch it in myFunc()
2. Or catch it in doSomething() and return null? (a very bad approach though). And then check for null in myFunc()

**Update:**
1. Value not found is something which is probable and not an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, is *value not found* something **exceptional** (indicating an error) or **probable**? If it is absolutely not possible that `doSomething()` can't find what it needs, this is an error. I guess `myFunc()` is not the right place to handle such error.

If `doSomething()` sometimes can't find this or that (because the input is incorrect, misconfiguration, etc.) then it should **not** throw an exception and let the client handle this *expected* situation. However `null` is not the best return value. Instead consider [null-object](/questions/tagged/null-object) design pattern or some wrapper like `Option[T]` in Scala.

This is one of the reasons why `InputStream` is not simply throwing [`EOFException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html) when it reaches end of file. This is not an unexpected situation.

In Java I try to follow some techniques/naming conventions to make `null` more obvious:

```
private Obj tryReturningSomething()
private Obj returnSomethingOrNull()
```

Also you can always use JavaDoc to document possible return value. I agree returning `null` is not the best approach (e.g. when method returns a collection, I always return an empty one instead of `null`) but in your case it is still better than throwing an exception to be caught one stack frame above.  This is wasteful, harder to maintain and read. Consider having two version - one returning `null` and one throwing an exception, wrapping the first one.

Exception handling was invented to handle errors, not to control the program flow.

Comment: @zengr: I added few tips to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A database lookup is a case where "no value found" is an expected occurrence.  Exceptions are for handling exceptional circumstances that do not happen in normal use.

The cleanest way is to change your database API to return null on no value found.  Then you do not have to worry about try/catch blocks at all and just propagate the null.

A nice side bonus is that using exceptions for flow control is relatively slow, so you will see nice performance improvements.

Comment: returning null is the null object antipattern right? http://blog.bielu.com/2008/12/null-object-design-pattern.html

Comment: @zengr: returning "*empty*" object is the *null object pattern* (not anti-pattern). Many consider returning `null` an antipattern.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Returning null is an antipattern. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

It's 6 of 1 and 1/2 dozen of another. It really depends on what you want to do with the end result and if doSomething() is going to be used outside of this single use-case. The advantage of not throwing an exception is that you can return a known value when the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Either approach is acceptable. The most important thing is that you document the behavior of your function.

If `db.getValue()` cannot return `null`, then the second option is probably easier. If it can, however, then you want a way to know whether the value is `null` or there is none.

Some standard library classes do it both ways, implementing one function that throws an exception and another that returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I am planning to do something like this (documented [here](http://blog.bielu.com/2008/12/null-object-design-pattern.html)):

```
public class NullUser extends User {  

  public static final NullUser INSTANCE = new NullUser();  

  public static NullUser getInstance() {  
    return INSTANCE;  
  }  

  @Override  
  public boolean isAuthenticated() {  
    return false;  
  }  

  private NullUser() {  
  }  
}  



    public User getUser() {  
      if (/*some condition*/) {  
        return user;  
      } else {  
        return NullUser.getInstance();  
      }  
    }  



if (obj.getUser().isAuthenticated() {  
  // allow  
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice implementation of *null object pattern* (which I am also referencing in my answer), probably the best solution from readability point of view. Consider naming your object `AnonymousUser` or `UnauthenticatedUser` to better reflect your intentions.